# Programmatically creating WPF/ASP.net CRUD UI from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have a requirement to build forms directly from a specific dataset format. I've gone one step of being able to create the database from the dataset using F#. Now I want to be able to create CRUD forms programmatically from the database. I've googled and checked for CRUD generators but couldn't find a suitable one for either WPF or asp.net. Websharper could have been a good option but F# is not an option as the employer wants C# even though the database generator was in F#. This I may have to convert to C# as well. Also I checked sharpkit but don't think is a viable solution. The reason for needing such a framework/application is that datasets come and go too quickly and design is not an issue. Having every time to design CRUD forms to be used just for a short while is tedious and time consuming.

Comment: 1. Do you have an actual question? 2. If that question is *Can you point me to an online resource?*, the answer is sorry, but no. That is specifically off topic for this website... please see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page from the Help Centre for further information.

Comment: Hey I"m looking too. LMK if you found something good. here's what i got :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36975/WPF-CRUD-Generator-Scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers CRUD scaffolding through the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore libraries. It can take an existing SQL table and generate the supporting object, controllers, and CRUD classes, or it can take an object class and create a local database.

Here is a good example of the former, generating CRUD classes from an existing database:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/will-perform-simple-scaffold-crud-operations-in-asp-net-core-using-ef-core/